# How to get change the port Play Authenticate uses for redirects and email URLs?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, play-authenticate

At the moment we're running our Play app on port 9000 with Apache as a front-end HTTP server like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName vms.gltd.net

    ProxyPass /http-bind http://vms.gltd.net:5280/http-bind/
    ProxyPassReverse /http-bind http://vms.gltd.net:5280/http-bind/

    ProxyPass / http://vms.gltd.net:9000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://vms.gltd.net:9000/
</VirtualHost>
```

However when a user signs up Play Authenticate uses the port from play.mvc.Http.Request which is 9000 not 80.

Is there a way to override the port Play Authenticate uses or do we have to move our Play app to its own server and run it on port 80?

thanks,

-Leon

Answer (score 0):

Try this, from [the Play documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/HTTPServer):

> ### Advanced proxy settings
>
> When using an HTTP frontal server, request
>   addresses are seen as coming from the HTTP server. In a usual set-up,
>   where you both have the Play app and the proxy running on the same
>   machine, the Play app will see the requests coming from 127.0.0.1.
>
> Proxy servers can add a specific header to the request to tell the
>   proxied application where the request came from. Most web servers will
>   add an X-Forwarded-For header with the remote client IP address as
>   first argument. If the proxy server is running on localhost and
>   connecting from 127.0.0.1, Play will trust its `X-Forwarded-For` header.
>   If you are running a reverse proxy on a different machine, you can set
>   the `trustxforwarded` configuration item to true in the application
>   configuration file, like so:
>
> ```
> trustxforwarded=true
> ```
>
> However, the host header is untouched, it’ll remain issued by the proxy. If you use Apache 2.x, you can add a directive like:
>
> ```
> ProxyPreserveHost on
> ```
>
> The `host:` header will be the original host
>   request header issued by the client. By combining theses two
>   techniques, your app will appear to be directly exposed.
>
> If you don’t want this play app to occupy the whole root, add an
>   exclusion directive to the proxy config:
>
> ```
> ProxyPass /excluded !
> ```